# how to display a pdf file from database into an iframe using a button?

Tags: javascript, php

this is my code.but when there more than one pdf file in the db when i click on any button generated it will display the same pdf file int the iframe.

```php
<table>
<?php
$sql_ord=pg_query($conn,"select * from pp_upload where doc_type='".$doc_type."' AND regcase_type='".$case."' AND reg_no='".$regno."' AND reg_year='".$regyear."' AND judge_code='".$row_judge_c[0]."'") or die ('Query failed: '. pg_last_error());

while($row_ord=pg_fetch_array($sql_ord))
{
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="docview" id="docview[]" value="<?php echo $row_ord['path']; ?>">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="View" onclick="openPdf(document.getElementById('docview[]').value)"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
<iframe id="myFrame" style="display:none" width="800px" height="600px"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openPdf(docview)
    {
        var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
        omyFrame.style.display="block";
        omyFrame.src =docview;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i have added the postgresql query

Comment: `name="docview" id="docview[]"` - It's the name that should have the brackets: `name="docview[]"`, not the ID. Also, `id`'s _must_ be unique within the document so you can't hard code it in a loop since that would give all elements the same id.